# Naming substituted branched alkanes with different projections

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: Compounds]

Hi all, I would like some help with naming these two compounds.

For compound **1**, I know it is a 2-methyl-pentane, but I am unsure how to name the 3,4 $\ce{OCH3}$ compounds. I know that in the final name, it would be 2-methyl-3,4-di[$\ce{OCH3}$]-pentane (or vice verse depending on alphabetical order.).

For compound **2**, I am absolutely lost and would appreciate any help. At first I though it would be a bicyclic cycloalkane, but I steered away from that idea because of the three bridgeheads. Is it possible to have three bridgeheads? I just learned this content yesterday in class and have scoured through my textbook but have seen no mention of a compound like this one. If you could at least give my a general idea of how the 3D structure looks, that may help me. Thank you!

Comment: The O-CH3 group is methoxy. So I think the name of the first compound would be 2,3-dimethoxy-4-methyl-pentane.

Comment: The circle in the second molecule is looking down a carbon-carbon bond. The solid "Y" are the three atoms/groups bonded to the front carbon, the "broken Y" is for the three atoms/groups on the back carbon. Can you name it now? (This drawing method is used to show stereostructure.)

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) using LATEX syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the first one, it's called 2,3-dimethoxy-4-methylpentane. The $\ce{-OCH3}$ group is called methoxy. The second compound is a 
[newman projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman_projection)
. It is basically the view that you will see when you are looking down the $\ce{C-C}$ bond axis. The second one should be called 2,3-difluoro-2,3-dimethylbutane.

Here's what it looks like (http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.57499056.html?rid=29f2de9b-b762-46d4-a2ca-7452b8a5d6b6). In the newman projection you are looking down the the C2-C3 axis, and the arms show the substituents bonded to them.

Answer (score 0):

The name of first compound is 2,3-dimethoxy-4-methylpentane and the name of second one is Newman projection of 2,3-difluoro-2,3-dimethylbutane